# Java: Max and Min in absolute value

Tags: java

I'm looking for a method that given 2 floats A and B return the value (A or B) with lower absolute value.

Initially I tried

```
Math.min(Math.abs(A),Math.abs(B));
```

but it is not correct because for example for (-9,-2) return +2 and the return value I'm looking for is -2.

Is there some native/built-in for that?

Comment: Uh, why would that return 999?

Comment: The example was incorrect,updated

Comment: -2 is the correct result

Comment: Please look up what `Math.abs` does. If you just pass in `A` and `B`, you would have gotten `-2`.

Comment: @Baz I think what Sean meant was that OP wanted `-2`.

Comment: @Baz the question always asked for the arg with lower absolute value, despite bad first example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Math.abs(A) < Math.abs(B) ? A : B;
```

Comment: (In other words, there's probably no built-in, and it's just easier to implement yourself)

Answer (score 7):

I don't approve of using upper-case for local variables, but

```
 (Math.abs(A) < Math.abs(B)) ? A : B
```

Answer (score 5):

`Math.min()` returns the lowest of the two parameters passed into it. In the example above, you're providing it with arguments of `999` and `2` (The absolute values generated by `Math.abs()`.

You could replace the `Math.min()` call with something like:

```
Math.abs(A) < Math.abs(B) ? A : B;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
val = (Math.abs(A) < Math.abs(B)) ? A : B;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a correct behaviour.

You're getting the absolute value of both numbers inside the Min funcion which returns the minimum value of both. In your case that's 2 because you're comparing 9 and 2.

**EDIT**

AFAIK There's not built-in way to do what you want to do. As others have suggested, you have to make the comparation yourself with something like:

```
Math.abs(A) < Math.abs(B) ? A : B
```

Just remember to be careful with the types you compare and the result.

Comment: I know its correct behaviour, I'm asking for a built-in way of getting my initial goal